# How can I develop from more than one machine?

Tags: version-control, github-for-windows

Is Clone the only way for me to get my own repository to a different machine?

I have published my repository from my home PC and am trying to edit it from another.

I'm using Github for Windows but cannot see how to get the published repository to a second machine in order to edit the code and republish the changes so I can later use on the original PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach for Distributed Version Control Systems is to:

1. Clone the repository (from the server)
2. Update your code (local, in your working directory)
3. Commit the code (local, in your working directory)
4. Push the commits (to the server)
5. Pull the new commits (from the server) to another development PC.

Typical development cycles iterate between steps 2 and 3. And sometimes 4 (to store your changes off-site) and 5 (to grab changed made by others).

As I suppose that 'Github for Windows' uses git(hub), it is also a DVCS and works also with these steps.

Comment: So Clone is what I should use. I'm trying it but it does not download any files. I can see the files in my online repository but when I use the "Clone in Window" it launches the GitHub windows app any no files come down nor do I see an option to. I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to clone the repository onto your second machine, straight from the source (Github).  Sharing one clone between multiple machines is not recommended except in a few circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
I had to delete the local repository. Github then prompted me with an error and the option to "Clone again", this clone again worked.

Thanks.